# PHP: what is the difference between $object::method and $object->method?

Tags: php, class, inheritance, methods

I always write:

```
$object->method
```

But I often see:

```
$object::method
```

What's the difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

-> is used when referring to a member of an object.

:: is the Scope Resolution Operator and is used to refer to a static member of a Class. For example

```
class test {
    public static function vehicle() {
        echo "Bus";
    }

    public function automobile() {
        echo "Car";
    }
}
```

You would call the function automobile() as

```
$test = new test();
$test->automobile();
```

and you will call vehicle function as

```
test::vehicle();
```